# Get file data then manually copy it

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a file then create an exact copy of it this way, I'm doing

```
f = open("new.mp3", "rb")
n = open("new2.mp3", "w")
n.write(f.read())
```

and, for some reason, when I try to run this, running `new2.mp3`mp3 won't play, it refuses to start, but `new.mp3` is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If copying the file is all you want, is there any reason why you can't simply use shutil? You can use a high level function like shutil.copy2(source, dest):

```
import shutil
shutil.copy2("new.mp3", "new2.mp3")
```

Anyway, if you insist on doing it your way, you need to open new2 in write binary mode.

Comment: The [copy2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy2) function tries to do a lot more than simply copy the file's data (which may not be what is wanted). The equivalent of the OPs original code would be `shutil.copyfile("new.mp3", "new2.mp3", follow_symlinks=False)`.

Comment: Granted, but is there a reason why op wouldn't want that?

Comment: For example, if the original file was read-only, would you usually want the copy to be as well? And what about the creation/modification date? Sometimes it makes more sense for the copy to have the current date (e.g. for the purposes of revision history and such like).

Comment: That's a valid point actually, which is why I explained what's wrong with his code just in case. Also, main reason why I suggested copy2 instead of copyfile is because copy2 will copy if destination is a directory but copyfile won’t. Tho I now understand that might not be of significant importance to op.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it - I was just pointing out (for the benefit of future users), that `copy2` is not the same as simply copying the file contents into a new file.

Answer (score 1):

The `b` for binary matters on output too (although you can get away with not using it in Python 2 on POSIX systems).

Comment: removing "b" made the file smaller than it should be and it won't run, using "rb" made the file the same length but still wouldn't run

Comment: @Hugh: What I mean is that you need `wb`!